# Long format of acronyms in italic

Tags: acronyms, italic

I'm using the acronym package and I would like to know if is there anyway I can set the expanded text of **all** acronyms to appear in italic, even if I'm calling them with \ac{}.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In the definition of your acronym you only have to write:

`\acro{TLS}{\textit{Transport Layer Protocol}}`

Then you can use it in your paragraphs typing:

`\ac{TLS}`

Now only *"Transport Layer Protocol"* will appear in italic letters and not the "(TLS)" after it!